# On iOS9 i can't set include recent 5 items in notification center,how to do it?

Tags: ios, notifications, ios9

I want to limit the number of item is shown on notification center,before iOS 9 we can set number in notification setting, but now Apple inc. take it out. how to set the number,can we use programming way to do?

Comment: My app has remote notifications,I want limit the number,this requirement is presented by our production manager...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. This feature is no longer available in iOS 9. Please send feedback to Apple requesting this feature back!

http://www.apple.com/feedback/